Automating Snowflake MFA, or some workaround
I have written Python code in VSCode which connect to snowflake every 6 hours and run some processes. Now the issue is that this connection to Snowflake I am not able to automate it, since a code is send in email for verification.
I’m not running the code in Snowflake because:
1. I have ipynb file which is not supported by Snowflake as of now, but I’m ready to convert it into py file if it works
2. There is a API call in the Python file which if I run in Snowflake gets blocked.

The API is taking data from some place and putting that into Snowflake.
If there a way to do so with Snowpipe Streaming API please let me know. I’m thinking maybe even there the API will get blocked.
Its actually taking data from Caspio.
I’m sure someone would have figured this out
I tried making connection every one minute to keep snowflake session alive.

Why are you using MFA, which requires manual intervention, in an automated process?
